# Handling multiple windows in IE and Chrome browsers

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In the below code,

```
//Element clicked in parent window
driver.findElement(By.id("ID")).click();

//Once after clicking the ID, system takes the user to a different tab in chrome and launches an external link
//In IE the same external link will launch in a new browser which is different from chrome behavior

Iterator<String> browsers = driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();
while(browsers.hasNext()){
driver.switchTo().window(browsers.next());

//Element to be clickable in the child window or external site
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button")).click();
```

Can anyone help me out how can we handle the scenario,i want something which works both in IE and chrome. Currently the above code works in chrome but not in IE as the external link opens in a new browser. I am not able to handle the scenario

Answer (score 0):

Try the below method for IE:

**Java:**

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING,true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR,"accept");
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS,true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL,"");
WebDriver dr = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

**C#:**

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
options.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Accept;
options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
options.InitialBrowserUrl = "";
string iedriver = TestContext.DataRow["IEDRIVER"].ToString();
dr = new InternetExplorerDriver(iedriver,options);
```